# Query to select limit in specific condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my table, I have the 'email' column. I want to select 1000 data where max 100 emails are 'gmail'. Is there any way to write one query to get data?

What I am doing is, to create two queries and then merge them.

```
SELECT email from my_table where email not like '%@gmail.%' limit 900;
SELECT email from my_table where email like '%@gmail.%' limit 100;
```

Comment: What is wrong with your approach (except that you only need to add a `union`)?

Comment: union wont work with limit probably

Comment: union will work, you only need to add `()` around the individual queries. (But if you really need 1000 emails, the solution from @Zakaria is better)

Comment: BTW: you should add an `ORDER BY` to your queries if you want to be sure that, between different calls, the same email will be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `union all` should be it. However, to make sure that you're getting exactly 1000 rows (in case there are more than 1000 rows but less than 100 are @gmail) you can do this:

```
with u as 
(SELECT email from my_table where email like '%@gmail.%' limit 100)
select * from u
union all
(SELECT email from my_table 
where email not like '%@gmail.%' 
limit 1000 - (select count(*) from u));
```

Comment: Can you use a sub query in limit clause?

Comment: @SalmanA seems to work yes: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3cc49156ffeaddfde574debe7b333802

Comment: Simpler: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=dfc8f06d1ff203a2f79c6be76a53e869

Answer (score 1):

probably there could be better answer but that one fix your problem:

```
select email
  from (
        select email,
               row_number() over(partition by 1) as rn
          from my_table mt
         where email not like '%@gmail.%'
       )q1
 where rn <= 900
 union all 
select email
  from (
        select email,
               row_number() over(partition by 1) as rn
          from my_table mt
         where email like '%@gmail.%'
       )q1
 where rn <= 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use cte functions to write this as a single query:

```
WITH 
query_1 AS 
(SELECT email from my_table where email not like '%@gmail.%' limit 900),
query_2 AS 
(SELECT email from my_table where email like '%@gmail.%' limit 100)

SELECT email FROM query_1 
UNION ALL
SELECT email FROM query_2;
```